# C# Wpf App e.Cancel = true unable to use! looking for keep application running in tray

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm unable to use the `e.Cancel = true;` in c# wpf its returning this error:

> CS1061    'FormClosedEventArgs' does not contain a definition for
> 'Cancel' and no accessible extension method 'Cancel' accepting a first
> argument of type 'FormClosedEventArgs' could be found (are you missing
> a using directive or an assembly reference?)

How do I solve it? looking for a quick solution or do I've any way to keep the application running on the tray?

Comment: FormClosedEventArgs is part of WinForms, which is a different UI framework than WPF. Apparently you are writing a WinForms application, so please set the question tags appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

In the XAML designer or in code behind of the Window element you need to add an event handler for the `Closing` event.

```
<Window ... Closing="Window_Closing">
    ...
</Window>
```

Here is the code for a `Closing` event handler method for WPF applications which will ask the user a question if they really want to close the application.

```
private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    // If user clicks No the application stays open
    if (MessageBox.Show(
        "Are you sure you want to exit the application?",
        "Confirm Exit:",
        MessageBoxButton.YesNo,
        MessageBoxImage.Information) == MessageBoxResult.No)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        // Keep application from closing
    }
    // Else the application closes    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You likely want to handle the `FormClosing` event instead - [FormClosingEventArgs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.formclosingeventargs?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) does have a `Cancel` property you can use to prevent the window from being closed.